# Abstract Algebra to find $\sigma^{2023}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations

given $\sigma$ is the permutation in $S_7$ and $\sigma = (1, 2, 3, 4)(1, 2, 5, 6, 7)$, find $ \sigma^{2023}$.

My idea is $\sigma^{2023} = \sigma^{7}$, then

$\sigma ^7$ = $(1,2,4)^7(2,5,6,7)^7 = (1,4,3)^2(2,6)^2(5,7)^2(2,7,6,5)$, then I found that $ (2,6)^2(5,7)^2(2,7,6,5)$ is not able to do multiplication.
Is that there is some mistake which I have did or what. Need some help, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can write $\sigma $ as a product of disjoint cycle as follow : $$\sigma =(134)(2567).$$
Therefore, $\sigma ^{12}=id$. Moreover, $$2023=168\times 12+7,$$
and thus, $$\sigma ^{2023}=\sigma ^7=(134)^7(2567)^7=(134)(2567)^3=...$$

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).